# Dynamic ImageView Animation

Tags: android, imageview

I have a FrameLayout and add 10 ImageViews dynamically to it.
I then fill it with an downloaded Image and want to animate it. 
Scale and Translate animation starts at a wrong position. It should start from the middle of the screen. When I change the drawable(with another downloaded image) in the ImageView during runtime and animate it again the animation starts at the right position( from the middle of the screen).

I think i have to initialize the position somehow.

This is how i create the imageViews:

```
mImages = new ImageView[10]; //Fill Array with ImageViews
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferCount; i++){   // ,Initialize them
        mImages[i]= new ImageView(mCtx);
        mImages[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);//,make them Invisible
        ContentFrame.addView(mImages[i]);   //and add them to the view
    }
```

and this is my Animation:

```
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mCtx ,R.anim.anim1);
        animation.setAnimationListener(mAnimationDone);

        mImages[imgPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImages[imgPos].startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Animation

```
<scale
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="2.0"
android:toYScale="2.0"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
/>


<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.5" 
     /> 

</set>
```